# CiviCRM + Wordpress + Contact 7, how to get it to work

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make sense of this WP plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-civicrm-integration/

I have installed it, set the API details, and am now setting it up. The emails get sent, but there is no addition to civicrm.
Right now the civicrm options of contact 7 via this plugin are:

Entity: Contact
Action: create
(all good here, I guess)

Additional parameters (the standard ones given): contact_type=Individual&source=Wordpress
What if I wanted to add this user to a specific group too? I'm not sure about what to write.

In any case, by filling the form an email gets sent, but no addition to CiviCRM is made...! This would be quite important to me, so if anyone had any idea or has any experience with contact 7, any help would be really, really appreciated.

On a secondary note: how do I know the standard names of all "fields"? In the plugin page they give "first_name" and "last_name" as samples, but what if I want to add a phone number and/or email? What standard CiviCRM names should I use? I have not found a list yet, and I've searched for a while...

If anyone had any idea, it would be awesome :) thank you in advance, and sorry for being a bit noobish.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction.
I replaced contact7 with Caldera and, even though this created a bit of integration issues, it works flawlessly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

You must also install a CiviCRM extension on the other end - see [this blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/send-wordpress-contact-form-7-data-to-civicrm-with-api) for details.

Note that this plugin is NOT very mature, and isn't recently updated.  Its killer feature is the ability to post data to a *remote* CiviCRM.

If the CiviCRM you're trying to post to is installed on the same WordPress site, then you'll want to use [Caldera Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/) with its [CiviCRM integration](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm).  This is the plugin of choice for CiviCRM/WordPress developers and is receiving active support.

Answer (score 2):

As JonG mentioned, this extension is developed to send ALL data on a Wordpress form over to a REMOTE CiviCRM. The receiving CiviCRM will then have to do something to receive and process the data. The organization we developed this with also has a customized CiviCRM native extension to process the data it receives.

If you are a developer and want to use this as a basis we would happily explain what is in the extension. If you are not I would not recommend using it. Go with the the Caldera Forms as JonG suggests.